# LeetCode 125: Palindrome Number Easy Leetcode

Tags: javascript, algorithm, palindrome

This is my answer. However, I couldn't pass the test case for "11".
I couldn't find what is wrong in the code. Please help! Thank you!

```js
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    if (x === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if (x < 0 || x % 10 === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    let rev = 0;
    
    while (x > rev) {

        pop = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + pop;
    }
    
    if (x === rev || x === rev / 10) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Original leetcode question link https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number

Answer (score 1):

Finding palindromes is inherently something which you would typically do using *strings*, not numeric variables, so I suggest converting your number to a string, and going from there:

```js
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    x = x + "";   // convert to string, if x be a number
    var isPalindrome = true;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length/2; i++) {
        if (x.substring(i, i+1) != x.substring(x.length-1-i, x.length-i)) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isPalindrome;
}

console.log(isPalindrome(1234321));
console.log(isPalindrome(1234329));
```

The strategy here is just to iterate half the string, and assert that each character matches its counterpart in the other half.  Note that we don't need to check the middle character, in the case of an input with an odd number of characters.

Comment: why substring instead of using index to access elements of string ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I'm a Java developer (can you tell) `:-)`

Comment: Ahh got it :), That seemed like overkill to me, we can simple access string element using index, i.e `string[index]`

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be [LeetCode 9](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/) and in the discussion board, there are good accepted solutions such as:

#### JavaScript

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    if (x < 0) 
        return false;

    let reversed = 0;
    for (let i = x; i > 0; i = Math.floor(i / 10)) 
        reversed = reversed * 10 + i % 10;

    return reversed === x;
};
```

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        if x < 0 or (x > 0 and not x % 10):
            return False

        return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        if (x < 0 || (x != 0 && x % 10 == 0))
            return false;

        int reversed = 0;

        while (x > reversed) {
            reversed = reversed * 10 + x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }

        return (x == reversed || x == reversed / 10);
    }
}
```

---

There is another similar [isPalindrome question](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/) that if you might be interested, I've just copied below:

#### JavaScript I

```
var isPalindrome = function(s) {
    var original = s.replace(/\W/g, ''); // means NON-WORD characters  
    var reversed = original.split('').reverse().join('');

    return original.toLowerCase() == reversed.toLowerCase();
};
```

#### JavaScript II

```
var isPalindrome = function(s) {
    var original = s.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/isg, '');
    var reversed = original.split('').reverse().join('');

    return original.toLowerCase() == reversed.toLowerCase();
};
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        String original = s.replaceAll("(?i)[^a-z0-9]", "").toLowerCase();
        String reversed = new StringBuffer(original).reverse().toString();
        return original.equals(reversed);
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s):
        s = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?is)[a-z0-9]+', s)).lower()
        return s == s[::-1]
```

- `\W` (non-word-character) matches any single character that doesn't match by `\w` (same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

#### Reference

You can find additional explanations in the following links:

- [LeetCode 9 JavaScript Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=&tag=javascript)
- [LeetCode 125 JavaScript Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=&tag=javascript)

Comment: The question you linked is not what op was asking for here the actual question op was asking https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number

Comment: as the signature x is supposed to be a number not string. i.e. /**
 * \@param {number} x
 * \@return {boolean}
 */

Comment: No problem, i just removed the linked question from OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Using string for checking palindrome is very easy and straight forward. Having said that if you want to see how you can do it without changing number to string,

- First initialise an variable start with `Math.pow(10, digit count-1)`
- Loop till the value of start is greater than 0

  - inside loop compare the first and last digit if they are not equal return false
  - on each iteration remove the first and last digit from x and reduce start by 100

```js
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    // as per question on leetcode negative values cannot be palindrome
    if( x < 0) {
      return false
    }
    x = Math.abs(x)
   // to get the digits from start we need to get log10 of given value
    let len = Math.ceil( Math.max( Math.log10(x), 1 ) ) - 1
    let start = Math.pow(10, len)
    while(start){
    // compare first digit with the last digit
    if(Math.floor(x/start) != (x % 10)){
      return false
    }
    // remove first digit of current x
    x = x % start
    // remove last digit of current x
    x = Math.floor(x/10)
    // reduce start by 100 as we removed 2 digits
    start = Math.floor(start / 100)
   }
   return true
};

console.log(isPalindrome(1))
console.log(isPalindrome(1221))

console.log(isPalindrome(-121))
console.log(isPalindrome(12341))
console.log(isPalindrome(100111))
```

**Note:-** We do `(digit count - 1)` so that we can capture the first digit

[`Original leetcode question link`](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number)